# Setting up a LAMP server on Centos with Win7 and VirtualBox.

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, lamp, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a LAMP server on Centos with Win7 and VirtualBox](https://serverfault.com/questions/333015/setting-up-a-lamp-server-on-centos-with-win7-and-virtualbox)

Did anybody get it up and running or know a good place on the net when I can find info about it. Setting up LAMP on Linux (CentOS 6 in my case) is not difficult, but it is kind of hard to figure out configuration (Linux) and network settings (VirtualBox). There is not too much info about it in VB manual either.

So far I know that the best option is to use host-only option to connect CentOS (on VB) to Win7, and then add second virtual NIC set to NAT to enable the internet acces for CentOS.

Another thing that seems to be involved in this is changing the hostname in Linux and making changes in configuration files, like /etc/httpd/config/httpd.config and /etc/sysconfig/network.

Thank you.

Comment: Should be moved to http://ServerFault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible I use only one NAT adapter with my virtual machines. When that isn't adequate I go straight to my favorite VirtualBox network setup--having one dedicated virtual machine performing NAT functions (I used Windows 2003 with Routing configured but a linux box would probably be even easier). On the NAT VM, Adapter 1 is attached to NAT and adapter 2 is attached to a new Internal Network of your naming. On every subsequent box, like your CentOS 6 box, you only need one adapter and it is configured to the same named internal network.

It's annoying to have to boot your NAT VM first, but it makes the network configuration so much easier on every other box. I've setup some pretty complicated test networks that included Windows domain controllers and several flavors of linux in this configuration.

Probably overkill for your situation.

In regards to configuring CentOS, you might read up on how to [change your hostname](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/redhat/change_hostname_without_reboot/index.php). I've used instructions like these to change ip, hostname, or domain name after a basic install on CentOS (CentOS is debranded Red Hat afterall).

Eventually, you may want to expose your LAMP stack to others. Search for "VirtualBox Port Forwarding" (my repuatation is too low for multiple links). I've used this for exposing ssh and web access into my virtual machines through my Win7 host before.